# Heroku doesn't create postgres database tables (and database itself) for rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have been trying to deploy my Rails applicaton to Heroku. It uses paperclip and SQLite at my computer and I am trying to use SQLite at my computer and PostgreSQL at Heroku.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

group :production do
  gem "pg"
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
  gem "pg"
end
```

My config/database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: tagitpostgree
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

And I have been getting those kind of errors at Heroku. The database is not being created I guess? Any hint?

The errors I am getting are like below:

```
C:\Sites\tag-it>heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3193
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
undefined method `has_attached_file' for User(Table doesn't exist):Class
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
/app/app/models/user.rb:17:in `<class:User>'
```

My migrations:

```
ls db/migrate
20121128000354_devise_create_users.rb
20121128000910_rolify_create_roles.rb
20121128000933_add_name_to_users.rb
20130827150824_create_data_files.rb
20130827154510_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb
20130827162448_add_avatar_to_users.rb
20130827183819_add_project_to_projects.rb
20130827191647_add_attachment_video_to_projects.rb
20130827195845_create_tags.rb
20130827211446_add_project_id_to_tags.rb
20130827213541_add_user_id_to_tags.rb
20130831173534_create_projectparticipants.rb
20130831184444_add_project_id_to_projectparticipants.rb
20130831184522_add_user_id_to_projectparticipants.rb
20130831190120_adicionando_index.rb
20130908135549_add_college_to_users.rb
20130908143105_add_function_to_users.rb
20130908143303_add_course_to_users.rb
```

Comment: In future questions, please take the time to make sure your error codes are formatted and wrapped correctly. When they're not easily read you discourage potential answerers from helping you.

Comment: Are you sure that you have your migrations in the right order?  ALso, looks like you are using something like Paperclip?  Is this in your Gemfile?  The errormessage is telling you is is trying to create a column on the User table, but the User table doesn't exist..  This can sometimes happen if the migrations are in the wrong order

Comment: Could you post the files that are in `db/migrate/`? Are you sure you've added all those files to git and pushed them to your heroku git remote before trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`? A few unrelated issues: heroku by default generates the `database.yml` from your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, so the `production` config in your `database.yml` isn't being used unless you're using a custom buildpack or something. Also, if you're not using postgres locally, I don't think you need the `pg` gem in your development/test groups.

Comment: As an aside, you should install PostgreSQL locally or create a dev PostgreSQL instance at https://postgres.heroku.com to avoid future incapability between development and production.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, this is my first post here. The first db migration creates a User table. Paperclip is at my Gemfile, I just posted part of it above. 

How can I know the Database settings at Heroku? Do I create a new DB there?

Answer (score 1):

You must read error message carefully.

```
undefined method `has_attached_file' for User(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

has_attached_file is paperclip method and I can't see paperclip gem in your Gemfile.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi, I have paperclip at the gemfile, I cut off this part on the post. 
Migrations are in the correct order :(

Answer (score 1):

Try running a rake db:setup. You'll also need to include the Postgres login information in your database.yml file.

Comment: I tried adding it manually from the Heroku information I got but no luck. :(

rake db:setup that's what I get:

d119cakihe65q3 already exists
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
undefined method `has_attached_file' for User(Table doesn't exist):Class